# How to achieve cross isolate concurrency in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, concurrency, hive

I have a use case where I am using multiple flutter engines (my flutter app is embeded in Android), each engine has it's own app instance.
I am sharing common data across engines with Hive.
But one problem is, I want to achieve concurrency as multiple writes (which are async, so in case many engines try to write once) can lead to issues.
I tried exploring 'synchronized' package but it doesn't support mutex for multiple isolates.

Comment: Hi, I also started with Hive and had the same considerations. Hive does not support concurrent access from different isolates. This is why I switched to Isar. Which does support that.
More broadly the problem of cross isolate concurrency includes not only sharing data but also critical sections. That is when you need to make sure that some code is not being run in parallel. This is the problem I am trying to solve right now.